# JavaScript click event not fired if child node is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working on a project where I can't use jQuery and I'm having an issue with the click event.

I have a link with an icon and some text and I want to create an event that when I click the link it gets added a "selected" class. 
The issue is that when I click a child node the class is added to it and not the link.

Here's an example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var actions = document.querySelectorAll(".action");
  
  actionClickHandler = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add("selected");
  };
  
  actions.forEach(function(action) {
    action.addEventListener("click", actionClickHandler);
  });
}
```

```css
.action {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 15px;
  background-color:#eee;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:8;
  color:#666;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.action:hover {
  box-shadow:0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-color:#ccc;
}

.selected {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="action">
  <i class="icon fa fa-comment"></i>
  Comment
</a>

<a href="#" class="action">
  <i class="icon fa fa-heart"></i>
  Like
</a>
```

What I want is that when I click anywhere on the link element (".action") the .action gets the class "selected" and not the child.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

[event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) returns the DOM element that the event linstener was attached to, as opposed to [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) which returns the inner-most element, the one that captured the event.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var actions = document.querySelectorAll(".action");
  
  actionClickHandler = function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("selected");
  };
  
  actions.forEach(function(action) {
    action.addEventListener("click", actionClickHandler);
  });
}
```

```css
.action {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 15px;
  background-color:#eee;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:8;
  color:#666;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.action:hover {
  box-shadow:0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-color:#ccc;
}

.selected {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="action">
  <i class="icon fa fa-comment"></i>
  Comment
</a>

<a href="#" class="action">
  <i class="icon fa fa-heart"></i>
  Like
</a>
```